# Will encoding protobuf messages in 64bit app and decoding in 32bit app work?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Proto n00b. I am encoding protobuf messages in a 64bit app and the receiving side is 32bit app. Such is the architecture at this time, and i am trying to understand if this will work.

Most of the proto scalar types seems to have a size defined except for float and double. So I am thinking this should work. But if there are other things to be concerned about in an environment like this, I know not and hence requesting help.

Thanks!!

Comment: They offers with:`Protocol buffers are Google's language-neutral, platform-neutral,...`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will work. The Protobuf encoding is completely independent of architecture.